# Consequence in Logic

Tags: logic

For arbitrary formulas $A,B,C$ it holds that:

1. $\{A,B\} \vDash C $ if $A \vDash (B \Rightarrow C)$
2. $(A \Rightarrow B) \vDash C$ if $A \vDash (B \Rightarrow C)$
3. $A \vDash C$ if $A \vDash (B \Rightarrow C)$

I know that only first one holds, can someone explain me why?

Comment: i can't recall  definition of  first   symbol,could you  remind me?first  proposition i meant

Comment: @dato you mean $\vDash$ ?

Comment: yes exactly  thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols

Comment: thanks for link @Jonathan Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

1. Note that trivially $\vDash p \to p$, so a fortiori $p \vDash p \to p$. But  $p \to p \nvDash p$ (suppose $p$ is false). So we can have an instance  of $A \vDash B \to C$ without the corresponding $A \to B \vDash C$.
2. Note that trivially $\vDash q \to q$, so a fortiori $p \vDash q \to q$. But of course $p \nvDash q$. So we can have an instance of $A \vDash (B \Rightarrow C)$ without the corresponding $A \vDash C$.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The canonical way to show that the two last implications *don't* hold would be to find formulas you can plug in for $A$, $B$ and $C$, such that the entailment to the right of the "if" is logically valid, but the one to the left isn't.

For example, try setting $B\equiv P$, $C\equiv Q$ and $A\equiv (P\Rightarrow Q)$, where $P$ and $Q$ are propositional variables.

Answer (score 0):

Number 3 Should be fairly obvious:

```
A entails (B implies C)
```

Which, in English, becomes:

```
A entails C or A entails not B
```

Number 2 is a bit more complex. The values it fails for are $A, ¬B, ¬C$.